# JQuery - max number of "columns" classname

Tags: jquery, html-table

I would like to find the max number of elements per "column" and get the column(s) className. So, for instance, in the table below, I would get an array that contains `['class2', 'class3']` since both "columns" have the max num of elements. Help is appreciated.

**Updated layout:**
http://jsfiddle.net/2nbGe/5/

Comment: You might want to rethink your question, I don't think anyone really knows what you are asking.

Comment: I would like to get an array of class names by checking the max num of elements on each col. so again, if col1 has two elements and col[2-4] contain 4 elements, then col[2-4] will be in the array.

Comment: see fiddle for updated layout, as you can see, the last column has the most num of "rows", therefore, the array should contain only "class3"

Comment: also, note that there can be 2 columns with the same num of elements, so the output array will contain both classes

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var classes = {};
$("table td").each(function(){
    if(!classes[$this.attr("class")]){
        classes[$this.attr("class")] = 1;
    }
    else{
        classes[$this.attr("class")] = classes[$this.attr("class")]+1;
    }
})

//classes object will contain the each class and its count
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the number of each column using the following:

```
var firstColItems = $('.class1').length;
var secondColItems = $('.class2').length;
var thirdColItems = $('.class3').length;
```

then find max between firstColItems, secondColItems and thirdColItems.

If I understood correctly what you are asking....

Answer (score 0):

I used two .each() to achieve this. I hope you like it. :)

```
$('table').find('tr').each(function(){
     $(this).find('td').each(function(clNo){
        $(this).addClass('clumn' + clNo);
     });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics, it's hard to give concrete code; but the algorithm is the same for any scenario:

create an array of classes and get their count (this assumes the first row has all the classes):

```
var arr = new Array();
$('tr:first td')
    .each(function(i, o) {
        var c = $(o).attr('class');
        arr.push({
            class : c,
            count : $('.' + c).length
        });
    });
```

Get the max count:

```
var maxCount = Math.max.apply(Math,
    $.map(arr, function(o,i) {
        return o.count; 
    })
);
```

Filter the array based on max:

```
var arrMax = $.map(arr, function(o,i) {
    if (o.count == maxCount) return o.class;
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/CJ2av/

Answer (score -1):

```
var array = new Array();
$('table tr').each(function() {
   array.push($(this).children().last().attr('class'));
});
```

Comment: Isn't this just going to add `class3` to the array twice?  Also, don't use `new Array()` just use `[]`

Comment: I like using `new Array()` and what are you talking about? He wants an array of the last classes and this is what this solution does?

Comment: That's not what he wants. He wants the class of the column(s) with the most elements.